# Docker Container Sees Different IPTables Rules from Host

Tags: docker, iptables

I have a docker container which needs to add some iptables rules into the host. From searching, it seems like this is supposed to work either in privileged mode or by adding CAP_NET_ADMIN and CAP_NET_RAW and in host networking mode.

However, I tried both of these and no matter what I do the docker container seems to have it's own set of iptables rules. Here's an example:

on the host machine `iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them
```

(note that I ran docker with iptables set to false to try to debug this so it's a minimal set of rules, that setting doesn't seem to make a difference)

Next in an Ubuntu container: `docker run -it --privileged --net=host ubuntu:18.04 /bin/bash` same command (`iptables -L`)

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

so it's a totally different filter table, like it has it's own copy. Similar behavior for other tables and I've confirmed that adding rules in the container does not add them on the host even though the container is privileged and in host networking mode.

The host is a raspberry pi running Raspbian buster. Is there something else I need to do to make this work?

Comment: One of Docker's core design goals is that container and host network stacks are separate, and containers generally can't change the host's networking configuration.  Run this tool outside of Docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have thought of this earlier but I checked the raspbian kernel version and it was 4.19.something which is ancient at this point. So I re-installed with Ubuntu 20.04 server (which provides an arm64 distribution for the raspberry pi) and it seem to work as expected now. So likely it was something to do with the out-of-date kernel.